# Windows 7: measure mobile broadband connection traffic only - built-in tool?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, software-rec, mobile-broadband

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software to report internet traffic for home user](https://superuser.com/questions/107879/software-to-report-internet-traffic-for-home-user)

I have a WWAN module in my laptop which Windows 7 recognizes as mobile broadband connection. I would like to see how much traffic I'm generating over a month.

An freeware tool would also be acceptable, as long as it understands not to measure traffic over LAN or WLAN.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [NetWorx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) - it can measure and monitor traffic by-connection basis so you can simply choose to monitor only your broadband connection.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [BWMeter](http://www.desksoft.com/BWMeter.htm) in the past for this, although it's not freeware.