# Accurately determine data usage on a metered Internet connection

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection, isp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software to report internet traffic for home user](https://superuser.com/questions/107879/software-to-report-internet-traffic-for-home-user)

On my profile page of my ISP, I tracked that I used 100+ MB of data within 60 minutes of usage. During standalone downloading, my internet usually downloads @ 1 MB in over 1 minute. How do we know if our ISP is cheating on us, by faking our data usage?

Edit: Can we monitor our internet usage natively from Windows 7?

Comment: some information on your setup might help - the router I use has a built in set of graphs showing traffic usage per day and current usage - if you have a router that supports dd-wrt, it would make monitoring bandwidth usage a lot easier.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, I use a USB internet dongle.

Comment: Not enough to post as a answer, but to address your edit, there is nothing native in windows you could use without really hacking together some Performance Counters, Go with a free 3rd party software option that does the ugly tracking for you (never used it but that NetMeter that brett linked seems to be one).

Comment: See [Need to track total data transfer using Windows 7](http://superuser.com/a/227573), [Windows 7: measure mobile broadband connection traffic only - built-in tool?](http://superuser.com/a/136644) and  [Software to report internet traffic for home user](http://superuser.com/a/107891)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at: http://techpp.com/2010/07/04/9-cool-tools-monitor-internet-bandwidth-usage/

My favourite tool is NetMeter: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Bandwidth-Tools/NetMeter.shtml

Most ISPs are accurate so don't get too paranoid.